# Why does instanceof Observable return false in my tests?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a simple screen with a MatTable that uses an `Observable` as its data source. The data source is returned from an API service that fetches it via HTTP. (`Listener` is a plain value object.)

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  getListeners(): Observable<Listener[]> {
    return this.http.get<Listener[]>(this.listenersEndpoint, {headers}).pipe(
      tap(listeners => console.log("fetched Listeners")),
      catchError(this.handleError('getListeners', []))
    );
  }
}

@Component(
  template: `
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="listeners$"><!-- column definitions --></table>`
)
export class ListenersTableComponent implements OnInit {
  listeners$: Observable<Listener[]>;

  constructor(private api: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.listeners$ = this.api.getListeners().pipe(
      tap({complete: () => console.log("loaded")})
    );
  }
}
```

This works fine in production. For testing, I use a mock API service that returns an `Observable` of an array of `Listeners`.

```
  const apiService = {
    getListeners: () => {
      const list = [new Listener(), new Listener()];
      return of(list);
    }
  } as ApiService;
```

All the tests that use this mock fail with the message "Error: Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource", which originates in `@angular/cdk/esm2015/table.js`.  The code that fails in tests is:

```
   else if (this.dataSource instanceof Observable) {
       dataStream = this.dataSource;
   }
```

When I examine `this.dataSource` in the debugger, it's an `Observable` in both cases. The only real difference is that the value in test is an array, while in production it seems to be another `Observable`.

Can anyone tell me why the test version fails?

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve] of your issue, so that we can see what you have tried, and tell you what's wrong (if any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced this problem before and it's really hard to debug. The cause of the problem is, that there are two (or more) rxjs Observable class definitions in your project.

You can try these steps:

1) Make sure you only import `Observable` from `rxjs`, not `rxjs/Observable`.

2) Try to remove `rxjs/compat` if you're still using it.

3) Make sure the problem is not caused by any test config (tsconfig, karma.conf.js)

4) Make sure you only have one version of `rxjs` installed.

Comment: Thanks, I think that was likely the problem. I have to say it's completely mad to expose multiple, public versions of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple projects which depend on rxjs then make sure the versions match.

For example, my app had rxjs@^6.6.7 while [ionic4-auto-complete](https://github.com/jrquick17/ionic4-auto-complete) had rxjs@6.6.2 . Changing the versions to be in sync fixed the issue for me.